# driver.close() terminates the test

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I use selenium WebDriver. I am trying to run following scenario.

I launch a url, and I want to add a condition that if there is any url opened other than the one I intended, I want to close it.

Following is my code, I will explain whats happening with it below.

```
if (config.getProperty("browser").equals("Chrome"))
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        selectServer();
        String currentURL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
        if (currentURL != config.getProperty("production") || currentURL != config.getProperty("staging") || currentURL != config.getProperty("development"))
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10000); //for Debugging purpose
                driver.close();
            }
        }
```

I have a config.properties file where I set the browser / server  selection.

Now what happens is, when I launch the test, chrome launches and:

1. Chrome settings window opens and it asks me to restore default settings. (Window in display)
2. My intended URL opens up. (hidden)

When I run the test, the test passes but Chrome Settings window does not close. I tried to print the current URL , and it returns the production server URL which is my intended URL but the browser window in display is not my production URL.

Comment: The if condition is not correct. Change it to if(!(currentURL == config.getProperty("production") || currentURL == config.getProperty("staging") || currentURL == config.getProperty("development")))...

Comment: Still getting the same issue @Grasshopper

Comment: What is the value of the variable currentUrl?

Comment: @Grasshopper
https://aline.devfactory.com/login <-- this is the production server url and the same is returned when I print current URL in test. But when I run the test, the opened page is not the production server web page but is chrome settings page - chrome://settings/triggeredResetProfileSettings

Comment: In the stacktrace the error is coming from this -- at DevFactory.aLine.browserConfig.selectServer(browserConfig.java:32). This function call in the attached code is before the if condition

Comment: @Grasshopper Yes, I figured that out and called selectServer() before if condition (edited the code in question too). but now the test passed but still chrome settings window does not close.

Comment: Is it opening in a separate tab?

Comment: @BillHileman 2 tabs open when I launch test. The first one is chrome settings tab and this is the active tab, and the second tab is the one I want remain. but since chrome settings tab url is not any of my server url, driver.close() should only close it and it should not close the second tab which is my intended web page

Answer (score 0):

Based on your response in comments, I believe you need to switch to the settings tab, close that tab, then switch back to the original tab.  The below code should do that:

```
public static void closeBrowserTab() {
    String originalHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
    for (String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
        if (!handle.equals(originalHandle)) {
            driver.switchTo().window(handle);
            driver.close();
            break;
        }
    }
    driver.switchTo().window(originalHandle);
}
```